# JS Refrencing "this" when in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, scope, this

Part 1:

How would one dynamically reference a parent property from within a callback?

For example if we had this structure.

```
var someClass = {

   htmlClass : 'aFunClass',

   bindEvents: function(){

      jQuery(function(){
          alert( this.htmlClass );
      });
   });
}
```

Currently this will return "undefined" as its refrencing the jQuery function, rather than the parent.

Part 2:

What would be the most dynamic way of doing this? that supports the next following condition.

```
var someClass = {

   htmlClass : 'aFunClass',

   bindEvents: function(){
      var self = this;

      jQuery(function(){
          if( !jQuery('body').hasClass( self.htmlClass ) ){
              self = {};
          }
      });
   });
}
```

Currently if you do this - then someClass remains the same, and doesn't become an empty object.
Thus assigning it directly to another variable doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use variables scoped to the "this" you want to remember:

```
var someClass = {

   htmlClass : 'aFunClass',

   bindEvents: function(){
      var that = this;
      jQuery(function(){
          alert( that.htmlClass );
      });
   });
}
```

Standards for naming of the local variable include `self`, `THIS`, `that` etc. Just go with something you like (I tend to use `THIS` in object oriented JS, but I mainly work with C# so anything "thisy" is good for me) :)

Comment: This method seems okay for just accessing information from within it - however it doesn't solve the additional problem that occurs when doing this, if you look at my addition to the question you'll be able to see. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The common practice is keeping a reference to `this` context in a variable:

```
bindEvents: function(){
      var self = this; // keep a reference to this
      jQuery(function(){
          alert( self.htmlClass );
      });
   });
```

Another solution is [binding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) the function to particular context:

```
bindEvents: function(){
      jQuery(function(){
          alert( this.htmlClass );
      }.bind(this));
   });
```